# Should I remove the CMOS battery?

Tags: password-recovery, safely-remove-hardware

I forgot my windows 10 password and I have no system image to restore my laptop to, plus it is not possible for me to reset my PC as I have some paid apps installed. I have to remove the CMOS battery to resolve the issue. Is this safe to do on a Fujitsu Lifebook A514 laptop?

Comment: Which password have you forgotten? Your BIOS password or your login password?

Comment: Are you sure the CMOS battery affects the password?

Comment: Just enable the built-in Administrator account and reset the password to your account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Windows 10 password is in no way tied to your BIOS / Motherboard etc. In this case removing the CMOS battery will do no good at all.

Password recovery settings for Windows 10 can be found here: https://www.howtogeek.com/222262/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-password-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

How would removing the CMOS battery resolve the issue?  That would drop the firmware settings on the BIOS which wouldn't affect the installed OS on the HDD.